# to hold a conversation VS to maintain a conversation

Tags: meaning, difference

Could you tell me please if "*to hold a conversation*" and "*to maintain a conversation*" are synonyms?
If not, then what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

"hold a conversation" is the term that you would generally use to describe talking to somebody in a normal situation.

"maintain a conversation" is generally used when the speaker's ability to keep a conversation going is being assessed: for example in a language exam, or when assessing people with learning difficulties, mental issues or behavioural problems.